# Rails Typos seen in the CLI while running `rails notes -a ["anything"]`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface, rbenv

I'm using up-to-date versions

```
.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails.rb
```

if you run `rails notes -a [" "]` you receive a clean list with NO typos. However if you run `rails notes -a ["literally_any_single_letter"]` every line that gets printed out is missing the first letter of their description. Very odd to me.

I understand I may not be using 'notes' correctly but I was diving around trying to learn and this is what I observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notes matcher is relativelysimple-minded. It searches for any comment that starts with one of the specified annotations. The default annotations are `TODO`, `FIXME`, and `OPTIMIZE`, but, you can specify any annotations you want with `-a` or `--annotations=tag1 tag2 ...`. If multiple annotations are specified, they are preserved in the output for clarity:

```
% rails notes -a TODO FOO
app/models/foo.rb:
  * [2] [TODO] Add stuff
  * [3] [TODO] even more missing stuff
  * [4] [FOO] this is foo
```

If you only specify one annotation, it 'eats' the annotation to clean up the output:

```
rails notes -a TODO
app/models/foo.rb:
  * [2] Add stuff
  * [3] colon is optional
```

So, if you define a single-letter annotation, you will a) get every comment that starts with the letter, and b) it will helpfully 'eat' the letter in the output.

```
% rails notes -a T
app/javascript/packs/application.js:
  * [  1] his file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files

app/models/foo.rb:
  * [  2] ODO: Add stuff
  * [  3] ODO colon is optional
```

Since your example included wrapping the annotation in brackets ([]), I should note that you might be surprised at the results doing that. The `notes` command allows you to use regular expressions at least in a limited way when specifying annotations. In Ruby regex, `[abc]` means 'match any one of a, b, or c'. So:

```
% rails notes -a [TD]ODO
app/models/foo.rb:
  * [2] [TODO] Add stuff
  * [3] [TODO] even more missing stuff
  * [4] [DODO] some dodo
```

Comment: Thank you! I can navigate this a little more clearly now